# Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: **method** is not defined", but it is clearly in the same location

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I've got a strange error that randomly happened today even though I've changed nothing and it was working yesterday. I'm getting an error that the method fetchColorPalettes() is not defined when it is called in the created hook. But it clearly is defined and it was working before. I have no idea what is happening.

In one file (palettes.vue) I have this code:

```
export default {
    name: 'palettes',
    data() {
        return {
            navItems: [
                {title: 'Palettes', selected: true},
                {title: 'Groups', selected: false},
                {title: 'Generator', selected: false}
            ],
            colorPalettes: []
        }
    },
    components: {
        'navbar': navbar,
        'page-header': pageHeader,
        'color-palette': colorPalette
    },
    methods: {
        // Get the color palettes from the Firestore DB and push them onto the colorPalettes array
        // TODO: Make this fetch only grab the palettes from current user that is logged in
        fetchColorPalettes() {
            db.collection("colorPalettes").get().then((querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc => {
                    const data = {
                        title: doc.data().title,
                        colors: doc.data().colors
                    }
                    this.colorPalettes.push(data)
                }))
            }))
            console.log("Fetching data");
        }
    },
    created() {
        fetchColorPalettes()
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the file that is giving me this error:

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:578 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: fetchColorPalettes is not defined"

found in

---> <Palettes> at src/components/pages/Palettes.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.esm.js?efeb:578
logError @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1713
globalHandleError @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1708
handleError @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1697
callHook @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2897
Vue._init @ vue.esm.js?efeb:4560
VueComponent @ vue.esm.js?efeb:4728
createComponentInstanceForVnode @ vue.esm.js?efeb:4242
init @ vue.esm.js?efeb:4059
createComponent @ vue.esm.js?efeb:5512
createElm @ vue.esm.js?efeb:5460
updateChildren @ vue.esm.js?efeb:5749
patchVnode @ vue.esm.js?efeb:5840
patch @ vue.esm.js?efeb:6000
Vue._update @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2647
updateComponent @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2765
get @ vue.esm.js?efeb:3115
run @ vue.esm.js?efeb:3192
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2954
(anonymous) @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1813
flushCallbacks @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1734
Promise resolved (async)
microTimerFunc @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1782
nextTick @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1826
queueWatcher @ vue.esm.js?efeb:3041
update @ vue.esm.js?efeb:3182
Vue.$forceUpdate @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2668
(anonymous) @ index.js?737e:221
(anonymous) @ index.js?737e:219
(anonymous) @ index.js?737e:104
(anonymous) @ Palettes.vue?dcb3:39
(anonymous) @ Palettes.vue?dcb3:44
./src/components/pages/Palettes.vue @ app.js:3097
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:679
hotApply @ app.js:608
(anonymous) @ app.js:290
Promise resolved (async)
hotUpdateDownloaded @ app.js:289
hotAddUpdateChunk @ app.js:266
webpackHotUpdateCallback @ app.js:8
(anonymous) @ 0.4e476bef286585c20fc2.hot-update.js:1
vue.esm.js?efeb:1717 ReferenceError: fetchColorPalettes is not defined
    at VueComponent.created (Palettes.vue?8bd4:56)
    at callHook (vue.esm.js?efeb:2895)
    at VueComponent.Vue._init (vue.esm.js?efeb:4560)
    at new VueComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:4728)
    at createComponentInstanceForVnode (vue.esm.js?efeb:4242)
    at init (vue.esm.js?efeb:4059)
    at createComponent (vue.esm.js?efeb:5512)
    at createElm (vue.esm.js?efeb:5460)
    at updateChildren (vue.esm.js?efeb:5749)
    at patchVnode (vue.esm.js?efeb:5840)
```

palettes.vue is referenced and displayed in my main app.vue via a router, but there is no code communicating with the palettes.vue file. It all takes place there.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: `it was working before` - before what? though you say you've changed nothing, something must've changed. note: I would've thought you'd need to use `this.fetchColorPalettes()`

Comment: Before as in 24 hours before I posted this, I clearly state that in the first paragraph it worked yesterday. I’ve touched nothing. Adding ‘this’ fixed it but I swear it wasn’t there yesterday when the code was running and working. Huh.

Comment: I have similar issues from time to time where I get a '[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"'. I think something goes wrong during the loading or with the order in which files load occasionally.
Haven't figured out how to fix it though :(